# ruby working on array elements in groups of four

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script  array when each element needs processing :

```
threads = []
elemets.each do  |element|
    threads.push(Thread.new{process(element)}}
end
threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
```

how ever due to resource limitations, the script works in an optimal way if no more the four elements are processed at a time.

no I know I can dump the each loop and use a variable to count 4 elements and then wait 
but is there a cooler ruby way to do it ?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can enumerate in groups of 4 for an array:

```
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].each_slice(4) {|a| p a}
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
```

So you can try something like

```
elements.each_slice(4) do | batch |
    batch.each do | element |
        threads.push(Thread.new{process(element)}}
        
    end
    (do stuff to check to see if the threads are done, otherwise wait )
end
```

Comment: @Rilindo: this is brilliant!  modified two lines and I  was good to go.  thanks.

Comment: (my) solution below should be more efficient when tasks take variable time to process. This solution assumes each thread will take the same time to process a list of 4 elements.

Comment: I think I just fell in love with Ruby all over again :)

Comment: If you're using Rails, there's the even more readable "in_groups_of"... elements.in_groups_of(4) do |group| blah end

Answer (score 22):

If I read you right, you want to have no more than 4 threads processing at a time.

Sounds to me like you should launch only 4 threads, and have them all read from a shared Queue (part of the standard thread lib) to process the elements.

You can have the threads end when the queue is empty.

Slicing the array into 4 equal arrays, and having each thread process 1/4 of the elements assumes that each element processes in the same time.  If some take longer than others, some of your threads will finish early.

Using a queue, no thread stops until the shared queue is empty, so it is I think a more efficient solution.

Here is a working program based on your code to demonstrate:

```
require 'thread'

elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def process(element)
    puts "working on #{element}"
    sleep rand * 10
end

queue = Queue.new
elements.each{|e| queue << e }

threads = []
4.times do
    threads << Thread.new do
      while (e = queue.pop(true) rescue nil)
        process(e)
      end
    end
end

threads.each {|t| t.join }
```

Comment: This solution is pretty close to perfect for me except that it throws an error upon completion: `ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block` Seems that it doesn't like the `while (e = queue.pop(true) rescue nil)`

Comment: I don't get that error, tried 2 versions of ruby - what version are you using?

Comment: Version `2.3.1`. I was running it inside of a rake task in Rails so it's quite possible that there is a conflict elsewhere.

Answer (score 14):

In **rails**(not Ruby) a more readble form can be used `in_groups_of`

```
arr= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
arr.in_groups_of(4, false) {|a| p a}
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11]
```

The last row has only 3 elements as we have specified false as second argument in `in_group_of`. If you want nil or any other value you can replace false with that value.

Comment: `in_groups_of` is a rails method, won't work with plain ruby

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the following variant counts as just using a "variable to count 4 elements", or could be considered cool, but it gives you an array in slices of size no greater than 4 elements:

```
x = (1..10).to_a
0.step(x.size - 1, 4) do |i|
    # Choose one
    p x.slice(i, 4)
    p x[i, 4]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to do some method overriding. Usual approach is to override '/' for `Array` like so:

```
class Array
  def / len
    a = []
    each_with_index do |x,i|
      a << [] if i % len == 0
      a.last << x
    end
    a
  end
end
```

And with that defined you can now easily do:

```
foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
foo / 2
# Result is [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Comment: I think that overriding methods on such basic classes is rather dangerous - even if (like in this case) they weren't defined before. Why is it `/` and not `%`? What if another developer (or I, who implemented this) comes by in a year or two and wants to make sense of the code, asking "what the heck does an `Array` divided by a number actually mean"?