# Outlook GetGlobalAddressList.AddressEntries query takes 30+ minutes

Tags: ruby, outlook, win32ole

This is NOT a ruby question, this is more of an Outlook question, but my example is written in Ruby.

I have a ruby script that has been poly-morphed from an old Vb-script, and it is being used to download contacts from my organizations outlook server.

This query takes 30+ minutes to obtain 500+ contacts because it makes synchronous queries for each individual field name, this is not an acceptable amount of time for it to take for only 500 contacts. This is a super inefficient way to query for contacts.

How can someone query for the all the individual fields in one single request rather than each of the 500 `user_record` objects taking 30+ seconds to obtain all of its needed fields?

```
obj_outlook = WIN32OLE.new("Outlook.Application")
obj_namespace = obj_outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
obj_namespace.GetGlobalAddressList.AddressEntries.each do |entry|
  begin
    user = entry.GetExchangeUser
    next if user.nil?
    user_record = {
      first_name: user.FirstName,                         # synchronous request 1
      last_name: user.LastName,                           # synchronous request 2
      job_title: user.JobTitle,                           # synchronous request 3
      department: user.Department,                        # synchronous request 4
      company: user.CompanyName,                          # synchronous request 5
      phone_number: user.MobileTelephoneNumber,           # synchronous request 6
      email: user.PrimarySmtpAddress,                     # synchronous request 7
      manager: { 
        first_name: user.Manager.FirstName,               # synchronous request 8
        last_name: user.Manager.LastName,                 # synchronous request 9
        job_title: user.Manager.JobTitle,                 # synchronous request 10
        department: user.Manager.Department,              # synchronous request 11
        company: user.Manager.CompanyName,                # synchronous request 12
        phone_number: user.Manager.MobileTelephoneNumber, # synchronous request 13
        email: user.Manager.PrimarySmtpAddress            # synchronous request 14
      }
    }
    # do something to save user_record
  rescue => error
    puts error
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure whether Outlook has bulk queries, but If Outlook handles parallel requests, you can [iterate in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988274/ruby-working-on-array-elements-in-groups-of-four) and place each batch's iteration in its own [thread](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html). Or use a gem like [ruby-concurrency](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby)

Comment: unfortunately it does not handle parallel requests, it does allow asynchronous requests but users are also throttled with how many requests they are allowed to have open at a time =/